# Get the AIC or BIC citerium from a gamm, gam, and lme models: How in mgcv? And how can I trust the result?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am new to Gamms and gams, so this question may be a bit basic, I'd appreciate your help on this very much:

I am using the following code:

```
M.gamm <- gamm (bsigsi ~ s(summodpa, sed,k= 1, fx= TRUE, bs="tp") + s(sumlightpa, sed, k=1, fx= TRUE, bs="tp") , random = list(school=~ 1) , method= "ML", na.action= na.omit, data= Pilot_fitbit2)
```

The code runs, but gives me this feedback:

> Warning messages: 1: In smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object,
>   dk$data, dk$knots) :   basis dimension, k, increased to minimum
>   possible
>
> 2: In smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
>   basis dimension, k, increased to minimum possible

Questions:

1. My major question is however how I can get an AIC or BIC from this?
   I've tried `BIC(M.gamm$gam)` and `BIC(M.gamm$lme)`, since gamm exists of both parts (lme and gam), and for the latter one (with lme) I do get a value, bot for the first one, I don'get a value. Does anyone know why and how I can get one? 
   The issue is that I would like to compare this value to the BIC value of a gam model, and I am not sure which one (`BIC(M.gamm$lme)` or `BIC(M.gam$gam)`) would be the correct one. It is possible for me to derive a BIC and AIC for the gam and lme model.
2. If I'd be able to get the AIC or BIC for the gamm model - how can I know I can trust the results? What do I need to be careful with so I interpret the result correctly? Currently, I am using ML in all models and also use the same package (mgcv) to estimate lme, gam, and gamm to estabilish comparability.

Any help/ advice or ideas on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Best wishes,
Noemi

Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Why are you setting k=1 within the smoothers? That's a serious mistake. Then I'd suggest using gam instead of gamm, see this paper: https://peerj.com/articles/6876/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warnings come as a result of requesting a smoother basis of a single function for each of your two smooths; this doesn't make any sense as both such bases would only contain equivalent of constant functions, both of which are are unidentifiable given you have another constant term (the intercept) in your model. Once *mgcv* applies identifiable to constraints the two smooths would get dropped entirely from the model.

Hence the warnings; *mgcv* didn't do what you wanted. Instead it set `k` to be the smallest values possible. Set `k` to something larger; you might as well leave it at the default and not specify it in the `s()` if you want a low rank smooth. Also, unless you really want an unpenalized spline fit, don't use `fix = TRUE`.

I'm not really familiar with any theory for BIC applied to GAM(M)s that corrects for smoothness selection. The `AIC` method for `gam()` models estimated using REML smoothness selection does have some theory beyond it, including a recent paper by Simon Wood and colleagues.

The [*mgcv* FAQ](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/mgcv-FAQ.html) has the following two things to say

- **How can I compare gamm models?** In the identity link normal errors case, then AIC and hypotheis testing based methods are fine. Otherwise it is best to work out a strategy based on the summary.gam Alternatively, simple random effects can be fitted with gam, which makes comparison straightforward. Package gamm4 is an alternative, which allows AIC type model selection for generalized models.
- **When using gamm or gamm4, the reported AIC is different for the gam object and the lme or lmer object. Why is this?** There are several reasons for this. The most important is that the models being used are actually different in the two representations. When treating the GAM as a mixed model, you are implicitly assuming that if you gathered a replicate dataset, the smooths in your model would look completely different to the smooths from the original model, except for having the same degree of smoothness. Technically you would expect the smooths to be drawn afresh from their distribution under the random effects model. When viewing the gam from the usual penalized regression perspective, you would expect smooths to look broadly similar under replication of the data. i.e. you are really using Bayesian model for the smooths, rather than a random effects model (it's just that the frequentist random effects and Bayesian computations happen to coincide for computing the estimates). As a result of the different assumptions about the data generating process, AIC model comparisons can give rather different answers depending on the model adopted. Which you use should depend on which model you really think is appropriate. In addition the computations of the AICs are different. The mixed model AIC uses the marginal likelihood and the corresponding number of model parameters. The gam model uses the penalized likelihood and the effective degrees of freedom.

So, I'd probably stick to AIC, not use BIC. I'd be thinking about which interpretation of the GAM(M) I was interested most in. I'd also likely fit the random effects you have here using `gam()` if they are this simple. An equivalent model would include `+ s(school, bs = 're')` in the main formula and exclude the `random` bit whilst using `gam()`

```
gam(bsigsi ~ s(summodpa, sed) + s(sumlightpa, sed) +
     s(school, bs = 're'), data = Pilot_fitbit2,
     method = 'REML')
```

Do be careful with 2D isotopic smooths; both `sed` and `summodpa` and `sumlightpa` need to be in the same units have the same degrees of wiggliness in each smooth. If these aren't in the same units or have different wigglinesses, use `te()` instead of `s()` for the 2D terms.

Also be careful with variables that appear in two or more smooths like this; *mgcv* will do it's best to make the models identifiable, but you can easily get into computational problems even so. A better modelling approach would to be estimate the marginal effects of `sed` and the other terms plus their 2nd order interactions by decomposing the effects in the two 2d smooths as follows:

```
gam(bsigsi ~ s(sed) + s(summodpa) + s(sumlightpa) +
     ti(summodpa, sed) + ti(sumlightpa, sed) +
     s(school, bs = 're'), data = Pilot_fitbit2,
     method = 'REML')
```

where the `ti()` smooths are tensor product *interaction* bases, when're the main effects of the two marginal variables have been removed from the basis. Hence you can treat them as a pure smooth interaction term. In this way, the main effect of `sed` is contained in a single smooth term.